# Using Json with android app

Tags: java, android, asp.net, sql, json

I want to use json in order to import info from my ms-sql database to my android app.

So how do I do it? I am using this line to convert my data to json:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(info);
```

And what now? Where do I save this serialized data and how to get it using my android app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way is:

1. Get data from store (database) and serialize it.
2. Expose it via REST API.
3. Consume this API from the client (i.e. Android app) using [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) or [HttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html).

You've done 1), so now you need to desing your API (2) and consume it (3). I'm sure there is a lot of tutorials on this online.

Step 3) also involves deserializing JSON - you might use [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or standard Android [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html).

Comment: I managed to do steps 1 and 3, but I an not sure how to do step number 2. What is it REST API?

Comment: REST is basically HTTP with some payload (JSON or XML usually). For instance, your client (Android app) would do HTTP GET http://your.server/some/path and, in response, it could get HTTP 200 OK with JSON as a payload.

Comment: An example of REST API could be Google+ API - you can play around with it [here](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get#try-it) - it's a nice view, because you can see both request URI and JSON response. (just put "me" as an "userId")